# What's the optimal solution for 1D optimal transport

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming, earth-movers-distance

Assume I want to move `n` goods to `n` warehouses. I have a `n x n` cost matrix `M`, where `Mij` denotes the cost of transporting `j`th good to the warehouse. How do I find the transporting plan that minimizes the total costs?

I know there are many general optimal transform algorithms but is there any efficient algorithm tailored for this 1D situation?

Comment: Are there any other requirements or conditions aside from what's stated? Otherwise, why would you not simply choose the cheapest warehouse for each good? Is it the case that each warehouse can only receive one good?

Comment: O(n^3) algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm

Comment: @mhum Yes, each warehouse can only receive one good. Also, the number of goods is the same as the number of warehouses. So one warehouse's choice would affect all the other warehouses cause they won't be able to choose that good.

Comment: In that case, this is more readily modelled as an instance of maximum (bipartite) matching: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_weight_matching rather than as an optimal transport problem

Comment: How is this 1D if you have an nxn matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution as [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).